# Check if there are two items in an array whose sum is equal to a given value with es6-arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

The following code detects if in a given array `arr` there are two items whose sum is equal to the value given in the variable `sum`. To address this problem the complementary values (`sum-item`) are stored into a Set.

Although I know the arrow functions and how functional `some()` function works, the syntax is obscure to me and I struggle to understand.

```js
const arr = [3,6,7];
const sum = 9;

const findSum = (arr,sum) =>
  arr.some((set => n =>
    set.has(n) || !set.add(sum-n)) (new Set));

console.log(findSum(arr,sum));
```

I can't understand the `(new Set)` inside  the `some` function (is a sort of IIFE? ) and how `n` is initialized to an item of `arr`,  in my understanding  the code `set` would initialized to an item of `arr`.

Someone can explain me how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change th formatting and have a look to the parts of the callback.

```
findSum = (arr, sum) => arr.some(
    (set => n => set.has(n) || !set.add(sum - n))
    (new Set)
);
```

You find two parts, one

```
    (set => n => set.has(n) || !set.add(sum - n))
```

is a function expresion which returns a function.

The other part is is an instance of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
    (new Set)
```

which calls the function expression immediately (IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression))) and acts as closure over `set`.

```
    (set =>                                     )
    (new Set)
```

The final part which works as callback is

```
            n => set.has(n) || !set.add(sum - n)
```

which takes a single value from the array, checks if the value is in the set or adds the delta to the set. Adding to a `Set` returns the instance and is truthy. This is unwanted and negated to prevent an early exit of the iteration.

```js
const
    arr = [3, 6, 7],
    sum = 9,
    findSum = (arr,sum) => arr.some(
        (set => n => set.has(n) || !set.add(sum - n))
        (new Set)
    );

console.log(findSum(arr, sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if we transform the arrow function into normal ones it will be easier to understand.

```js
const arrx = [3, 6, 7];
const sum = 9;

 const findSum2 = function(arr, sum) { //  (arr, sum) =>
  let search = function(set) { // set =>
    return function(n) { // n =>
      const r =
        set.has(n) || !set.add(sum - n); // same 
      return r;
    }
  }
  let init = search(new Set); // (..)(new Set) part
  return arr.some(init);
}

console.log(findSum2(arrx, sum));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I chose @NinaScholz' answer like accepting only because came first.

Comment: @Umbert I would pick the other answer even this one was quicker. It is way more explanatory than this.

Comment: Both responses made me understand the code and were helpful. I didn't know which one to choose and I used time as the main parameter.